# How do I upgrade weapons?

Tags: fable-3

How do I upgrade weapons in Fable 3? I see that my weapon can be upgraded in 3 different parts and I have to do specific things to level it up. But while I kill or do what the objective tells me to do it still stays at 0 eg "**Get 100 Human kills**

Comment: Do you have the selected weapon equipped? Are you killing with that weapon?

Comment: Yes I do have the selected weapon equipped and yes I am :)

Comment: Which weapon? There are only 50 of them lol...

Comment: It's from the evil do in the Dwellers camp, it's the one you have to show affection to another hero in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is an evil weapon, thus it wants you to kill innocent humans, rather than bandits and such. Try hiring a mercenary, then kill him with it?